# How can I calculate the MAE (mean absolute error) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have just started a data science course. I am stuck on an exercise, which I don't know how to solve. I am asked to apply the following equations. I have to calculate the MAE error (mean absolute error)  , ′ : MAE: 1/*∑=1∑=1∣−′∣

, ′ : MAE-corr: 1/2*∑=1∑=1∣−′∣

The dataframes that are needed to solve this exercise I already have them created. In this case X is the original dataframe, X' is the dataframe with the protected data, R is the correlation matrix of X and R' is the correlation matrix of X'. n is the number of rows and d is the number of columns.

```
from typing import Tuple

df_cor1 = df1.corr()

df_cor_noise = df1_noise_1.corr()

def information_loss(df: pd.DataFrame, df_protected: pd.DataFrame) -> Tuple[float, float]:
       df1.subtract(df1_noise_1)
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add more information about dataframe information like clomuns name,
to calcule MEA you can use this function but you should adapt it in your data frame variable .

## Creating a custom function for MAE

```
import numpy as np
y_true=X['y_true'] # declaring values 
predictions =X_prime['predictions'] #prediction values based on your datafram info
def mae(y_true, predictions):
    y_true, predictions = np.array(y_true), np.array(predictions)
    return np.mean(np.abs(y_true - predictions)) 

mae(y_true, predictions)
```